# How could the universe's expansion "remove the mean gravitational potential"?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, space-expansion

I'm citing W. C. Saslaw's *The Distribution of the Galaxies: Gravitational Clustering in Cosmology*, chapter 25, where he adresses (what seems to be a Newtonian approximation of) the thermodynamic formulation of the cosmological many-body problem, section 3, "The energy equation of state":

> We start with the cosmological many-body equation of state for the internal energy
>   $U$. It has three contributions: the average kinetic energy of peculiar velocities, the potential
>   energy of the gravitational interactions, and the potential energy of the global
>   expansion. [...]
>   Consider the average gravitational potential energy in a volume, which we
>   take to be spherical for simplicity. The number of galaxies in a shell around any specified central galaxy at $r=0$ is $\bar{n}(1+\xi(r))4\pi r^2\ dr$ on average [where $\xi(r)$ is a two-point correlation function and $\bar{n}$ is the average number density of galaxies]. Therefore the gravitational potential energy is
>   $$\frac{\bar{N}m\bar{n}}{2}\int^R_0\phi _{proper}(r)[1+\xi(r)]4\pi r^2\ dr \tag{1}, $$
>   since there are $\bar{N}$ possible central galaxies in the cell and each pair interaction contributes once. With $\phi_{proper}(r)=-Gm/r$, the first term of $(1)$ is
>   $$-\pi G\bar{\rho}M(R)R^2=-\frac{3}{4}\frac{GM^2(R)}{R},\tag{2}$$
>   [where $\bar{\rho}$ is the average density] which **diverges** as $R^5$.
>   The third contribution to the energy equation of state is from the global expansion whose potential is given by [the relation between the gravitational potential in proper coordinates, $\phi_{proper}$, and the potential in comoving coordinates, $\phi_{comov}$] [in Saslaw's notation, comoving coordinates $x$ are related to local proper coordinates $r$ as $r=R(t)x$]
>   $$\phi_{proper}=\phi_{comov}+\frac{2}{3}\pi G\bar{\rho}r^2=\phi_{comov} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ddot{R}}{R}r^2=\phi_{comov}-\frac{1}{2}R\ddot{R}x^2$$
>   as
>   $$\phi_{proper}-\phi_{comov}=\frac{2}{3}\pi G \bar{\rho} r^2 = \frac{1}{2}\bar{N}\frac{Gm}{r}.$$
>   The corresponding potential energy,
>   $$\frac{\bar{\rho}\bar{N}}{2}\int^R_0\frac{Gm}{r}4\pi r^2\ dr=\frac{3}{4}\frac{GM^2(R)}{R},$$
>   exactly cancels the divergent contribution $(2)$ of the mean field to the gravitational potential energy in $(1)$.

There are some points I don't understand in his argument:

1. Why can the term $\frac{2}{3}\pi G\bar{\rho}r^2$, which gives the difference between the expressions of the newtonian potential $\phi$ in both coordinate systems, be interpreted as the "potential of the global expansion" (what does this mean?) and therefore should be taken into account when computing the total gravitational energy of the system?
2. What exactly about the expansion counteracts the mean gravitational potential? From my understanding, the newtonian gravitational force/potential doesn't depend on the velocity of the particles, so it shouldn't affect it.
3. If the energy integral gives a divergence in proper coordinates $r$, which are already describing the expansion, how can this divergence, which physically is originated by gravity's long-range character, be removed by just a change of coordinates?

**Edit**: The treatment in the book seems to follow the derivation in this paper by the same autor: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1996ApJ...460...16S

Comment: The quoted text seems wrong from the first sentence. *We start with the cosmological many-body equation of state for the internal energy U.* Cosmological spacetimes in general relativity do not have a conserved, global, scalar measure of energy. Possibly Saslaw is not very competent in relativity, or possibly this is some sort of semi-Newtonian pseudo-derivation.

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes, I think he is using some kind of Newtonian approximation. He seems to follow the derivation in this paper: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1996ApJ...460...16S